Status of Rasha in the modern day
Is it possible for someone to have the status of Rasha (wicked person, such as if one threatens violence against a Jew) in the modern day? If yes, and even if not, what is the nafka mina of being a Rasha in the modern day? What are the halachot?

Should we hate or love them?
Should we exclude or excommunicate them?
Do they lose any priviledges, such as "don lechaf zechus", not speaking ill of them to others etc?
Do they become disqualified for anything such as being witnesses, being a shochet, aliyot in shul?

Etc.

The category definitely exists. There is a lot of discussion in poskim as to who qualifies.

@N.T. thanks, can you point me towards some discussions? Also, IIRC the Chazon Ish, among others, said we don't have bona fide Rasha'im today.

Chazon Ish says law of moridin v'lo ma'alin doesn't apply nowadays because there are so many reshaim it wouldn't help.
